# Cannot Drag and Drop any element from Storyboard to .h or .m file in Xcode 5 Using Yosemite

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

This is after I updated Yosemite, I think it is a Yosemite bug. Whenever I try to drag and drop from storyboard to .m or .h file, it will crash. Are there other people facing this problem? And is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing this problem as well and pretty much the only thing you can do is wait until the next beta of Xcode 6 drops. There are a few solutions though.

Reinstall Mavericks and install the Xcode 6 beta on that, because the crashes aren't happening for me when I use the older OS.

Comment: Yes I am well aware of that, but I am really not willing to downgrade my system.

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround is to manually add your declaration on your header and implementation file. Then it should be OK if you drag from storyboard or nib to your declaration.